# Good Tutorials on Hadoop Cascading

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cascading

Could anybody point me some simple examples,links and books to learn Hadoop cascading.I couldnt find any good resources except Cascading site http://www.cascading.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.cascading.org/documentation/ must be the best learning source for Cascading

My personal experience was: [Cascading User Guide](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.2/userguide/htmlsingle/) + [Cascading for the Impatient](http://docs.cascading.org/impatient/)

There's an O'Reilly book for Cascading: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028536.do

Also found an interesting 'Test driven learning' project:
[BertrandDechoux/cascading.learn](https://github.com/BertrandDechoux/cascading.learn)

other useful resources are available on: http://www.concurrentinc.com/resources/

If anything not clear, you can always ask questions on [user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/cascading-user) and get answers from there.